# CSS/HTML: Create a glowing border around an Input Field

Tags: html, css, input, border, glow

I want to create some decent inputs for my form, and I would really like to know how TWITTER does their glowing border around their inputs.

Example/Picture of the Twitter border:

[image]

I also don't quite know how to create the rounded corners.

Comment: Here's a tutorial that teaches you how: [CSS glow effects with box-shadow](http://blog.gesteves.com/post/475773360/css-glow-effects-with-box-shadow)

Comment: @Town 's link appears to be dysfunctional: redirect loop.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
.glowing-border {
    border: 2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.glowing-border:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/CXUpm/1/show/

(to view the code for the demo, remove "show/" from the URL)

```css
label { 
    display:block;
    margin:20px;
    width:420px;
    overflow:auto;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#444;
    text-shadow:0 0 2px #ddd;
    padding:20px 10px 10px 0;
}

input {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    border:2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius:7px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:5px;
    margin-top:-10px;    
}

input:focus { 
    outline:none;
    border-color:#9ecaed;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

```html
<label> Aktuelles Passwort: <input type="password"> </label>
<label> Neues Passwort: <input type="password"> </label>
```

Comment: How I can animate the glow?

Comment: @NSElvis e.g. `transition: box-shadow linear 1s` http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/6LyWe/1/

Comment: Very nice. One thing, if you only want this applied to text input fields, you'll want to restrict the selector: input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password], input[type=textarea].

Comment: @MichaelKennedy In real world applications, that wouldn't be enough. The standard approach would be classes, e.g. `.glowing-input { … }`.

Comment: Sure, my point was that was applying to radio buttons, submit buttons, etc. that might not be wanted.

Comment: @MichaelKennedy Ah yes, I see. Just `input { … }` is indeed bad code. I've changed it to a class.

Comment: I get a warning for box-shadow that it's not compatible with IE8. Is there an alternative for IE8?

Answer (score 33):

How about something like this... http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/Qwpq4/1207/

[image]

**CSS**

```css
input {
    border: 1px solid #4195fc; /* some kind of blue border */

    /* other CSS styles */

    /* round the corners */
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;


    /* make it glow! */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #4195fc;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #4195fc;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #4195fc; /* some variation of blue for the shadow */

}
```

Comment: This is not easing in and out

Comment: so what? the accepted answer doesn't do ease-in-out. the original question (and my answer) was posted in 2011, and I'm pretty sure Twitter's glowing borders weren't easing in and out either. further, the question doesn't focus on the ease-in-out, rather on how to make the border glow with rounded corners, which I've answered. I don't think you should be downvoting me just because there's no ease-in-out

Answer (score 7):

Use a normal blue `border`, a medium `border-radius`, and a blue `box-shadow` with position `0 0`.

Answer (score 4):

SLaks hit the nail on the head but you might want to look over the changes for inputs in CSS3 in general.  Rounded corners and box-shadow are both new features in CSS3 and will let you do exactly what you're looking for.  One of my personal favorite links for CSS3/HTML5 is http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/ .

Answer (score 4):

Modified version with little less glowing version.

```
input {
    /* round the corners */
    //background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 20px;
    width: 160px;
    color: #CCC;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;    
}

input:focus { 
    outline:none;
    border: 1px solid #4195fc; 
    /* create a BIG glow */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #4195fc; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #4195fc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #4195fc;  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I combined two of the previous answers ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TYetV/1/)).

```css
input {
    /* round the corners */
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;    
}

input:focus { 
    outline:none;
    border: 1px solid #4195fc; 
    /* create a BIG glow */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #4195fc; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #4195fc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px #4195fc;  
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="text"]{
   @include transition(all 0.30s ease-in-out);
  outline: none;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
input[type="text"]:focus{
  @include box-shadow(0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1));
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #007eff;  
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #007eff;  
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #007eff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that Bootstrap uses. Colors are bit different but the concept is same. This is if you are using LESS to compile CSS:

```
// Form control focus state
//
// Generate a customized focus state and for any input with the specified color,
// which defaults to the `@input-focus-border` variable.
//
// We highly encourage you to not customize the default value, but instead use
// this to tweak colors on an as-needed basis. This aesthetic change is based on
// WebKit's default styles, but applicable to a wider range of browsers. Its
// usability and accessibility should be taken into account with any change.
//
// Example usage: change the default blue border and shadow to white for better
// contrast against a dark gray background.

.form-control-focus(@color: @input-border-focus) {
  @color-rgba: rgba(red(@color), green(@color), blue(@color), .6);
  &:focus {
    border-color: @color;
    outline: 0;
    .box-shadow(~"inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px @{color-rgba}");
  }
}
```

If you are not using LESS then here's the compiled version:

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create glowing input fields and textareas:

```
textarea,textarea:focus,input,input:focus{
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
}

input:focus,textarea:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #7bc1f7;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.form-fild input,.form-fild textarea').focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
});

$('.form-fild input,.form-fild textarea').blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.open {
  color:red;   
}
.form-fild {
 position: relative;
 margin: 30px 0;
}
.form-fild label {
 position: absolute;
 top: 5px;
 left: 10px;
 padding:5px;
}

.form-fild.open label {
 top: -25px;
 left: 10px;
 /*background: #ffffff;*/
}
.form-fild input[type="text"] {
 padding-left: 80px;
}
.form-fild textarea {
 padding-left: 80px;
}
.form-fild.open textarea, 
.form-fild.open input[type="text"] {
 padding-left: 10px;
}
textarea,
input[type="text"] {
 padding: 10px;
 width: 100%;
}
textarea,
input,
.form-fild.open label,
.form-fild label {
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
     <form>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Name :</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Email :</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Number :</label>
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-fild">
            <label>Message :</label>
            <textarea cols="10" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -4):

You better use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) which contains all of this nice stuff inside. Particularly [here is](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) exactly what you want.

In addition, you can use different themes built for [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) from [this website](http://bootswatch.com/#gallery)

Comment: fixed broken link to bootstrap forms