# Binding to click-in and click-out events in textarea

Tags: knockout.js

I am implementing a knockoutJS-base client side comments system. I need to change the textarea style the moment the user has clicked on it to enable editing, and to style the textarea back to the defaults when a user has clicked somewhere else of the page (click-out) making the textarea inactive.

How do I bind to these events with knockoutJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put together a fiddle showing two different ways.  It is at http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/ckb9V/1/.

The first `textarea` shows how to add a class using knockout's `hasfocus` and CSS bindings. I believe this example shows how to do what you requested in your question. You can see [a full description on how this works at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html)

The second textarea shows how to do it with CSS only.  You can see a full description with this at "[CSS/HTML: Create a glowing border around an Input Field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5670879/136717)"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `event` binding to capture any events, and the `css` binding to style elements.

Here's a simple example using the focur/blur events: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/KXhem/48/

Comment: Heh seems me and photo_tom answered in the same instant. I forgot about `hasfocus`. +1 to photo_tom. I'll leave my answer up just cause it shows another KO way to do it

Comment: Thanks for upvote.  Your answer is a great example of how to use the event binding.