# minimal bootstrap css to include in an existing project

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, customization, squirrelmail

I would like to create a custom Stylesheet for SquirrelMail.

How do I get the round-corners and the blue glow from bootstrap in a single css-file, that I could include in SquirrelMail?

I already figured out how to [create glowing input fields and textareas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23391008/1069083)

Comment: Download Bootstrap and extract the CSS rules, that you need, out of it.

Answer (score 0):

This will create glowing input fields and textareas:

```
textarea,textarea:focus,input,input:focus{
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #d9d9d9;
}

input:focus,textarea:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #7bc1f7;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #7bc1f7;
}
```

Otherwise you would have to extract the CSS rules from a [customized bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), but that will most likely result in a large and unreadeable file.