# How to validate form input before submiting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I have a form with two input : one for Hostname another for ip address. how can i validate these two fields before submit the form and if they are not match with their pattern show an error.for example :Enter correct hostname.
here is patterns:

```
Host : ^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$

Ip : ^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$
```

Here is my snippet but it is not working :

```js
$('#hosti').focusout(function() {
    $('#hosti').filter(function() {
        var hosti = $('#hosti').val();
        var hostiback = $('#hosti');
        var hostiReg = /^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/;
        if (!hostiReg.test(hosti)) {
            $('#hosti').css('boxShadow', '0px 0px 2px 1px #E25249');
        } else {
    $('#hosti').css('boxShadow', '0px 0px 0px 0px #E25249');
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  HOST :
<input type="text"  placeholder="Host" id="hosti" pattern="/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/"/>
  
  IP ADDRESS :
  <input type="text"  placeholder="IP Address" pattern="/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/"/>

  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Use `required` attribute

Comment: i want to validate form with their pattern if i use required attribute. it is just check the field that empty or not.

Comment: The `pattern` regex should not contain `/` delimiters. To display an error message, an `input` must have a `title` attribute.

Comment: See [this JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0b300qo3/2/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `pattern` regexps cannot have regex delimiters, the `/` must be removed. Also, these patterns are anchored by default (i.e. wrapped within `^(?:` and `)$`), the `^` and `$` are not necessary in the patterns you have.

To show an error message on submit, you need to add `title` attributes to the `input` nodes.

Also, you may add CSS styles to `invalid` and `valid` properties of the elements being validated.

See a demo below and a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0b300qo3/2/):

```css
.to_validate:valid {
  color: black;
  border: 5px solid #dadadada; // dadada .glowing-border: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670879/css-html-create-a-glowing-border-around-an-input-field
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.to_validate:invalid {
  color: navy;
  outline: none; // .glowing-border:focus 
  border-color: #ff1050;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ff0000;//#9ecaed
}
```

```html
<form>
  HOST :
<input type="text"  placeholder="Host" class="to_validate" id="hosti" pattern="(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])" title="Wrong Host"/>
  IP ADDRESS :
  <input type="text" class="to_validate"  placeholder="IP Address" pattern="(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" title="Wrong IP"/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you want to fail a match once the whole *HostName* field input is equal to a *number* +`.`+ *number* +`.`+ *number* +`.`+ *number* pattern, add a `(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)` negative lookahead at the start:

```
pattern="(?!\d+(?:\.\d+){3}$)(([a-zA-Z\d]|[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])\.)*([A-Za-z\d]|[A-Za-z\d][A-Za-z\d-]*[A-Za-z\d])"
```

See a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0b300qo3/3/).

This lookahead matches 1 or more digits, and then 3 sequences of a dot and 1+ digits, and then the end of string (here, we need to define the end of string pattern explicitly as it is not at the end of the pattern).

Comment: It seems SO does not let the messages trigger in the sandboxed code, see the external JSfiddle to see the error message demo.

Comment: when the hostname field with for example :192.168.0.100 it almost show correct. but it's an ip address not a host name.what is the problem do you think?

Comment: The host field pattern also matches IP addresses, do you want to disallow them? See https://jsfiddle.net/0b300qo3/3/, where I added a negative lookahead at the start that will fail the match once the whole input looks like *number* +`.`+ *number* +`.`+ *number* +`.`+ *number*. I am somewhat unsure of what the requirements you need for the hostname part.

Comment: i want to add only name in host filed. in your newe fiddle when in host fileld i wrote : 192.168.178 it was still valid !

Comment: Yes, that is valid because it only contains 3 numbers separated with dots, and an IP string requires 4 sections. So, it is not an IP. **What are your *exact* requirements**? Do you want to fail the match if there are digits/dots only? Use `(?![\d.]+$)` lookahead then. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0b300qo3/4/).

Answer (score 3):

Dunno what the `focusout` function is about... Why would you need that?

The `pattern` attribute handles what you need. You have however used the same pattern for both fields. And as Wiktor pointed out - you don't use the `/` for patterns. I've also added `required`.

This HTML should be all you need to make it work:

```
<form>
HOST :
<input type="text"  placeholder="Host" id="hosti" pattern="^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$" required/>

IP ADDRESS :
<input type="text"  placeholder="IP Address" pattern="^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$" required/>


  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It appears as if SO's snippets don't support forms, but you can see it [here at JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7m1hh6s/).

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you're trying to achieve is an intermediate state between the button click event and form submission.
What you can do is remove the `type="submit"` attribute from the button and capture the button click event, where you can validate your inputs and then submit the form. Something like this:

```
$("#submit_button").on("click", function() {
  /* DO ALL YOUR REQUIRED INPUT VALIDATIONS AND DISPLAY ERRORS */
  $("#my_form").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use validation engine plugin (https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) and drop inside your patterns

Or just use input mask for users clarity with your patterns (https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

Last is less safe but anyway backend validation is inevitable

Answer (score 1):

Check this out try put some value in host input and see

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "input[name='host']")
   .focusout(function() {
     var pat_h  = $( "input[name='host']").attr("pattern");
     var val = $( "input[name='host']").val();
     var reg = new RegExp("^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$");
     if(reg.test(val)){
      alert("match")
     }
     else{
       alert("not match");
     }

   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  HOST : 
  <input  type="text"  placeholder="Host" id="hosti" pattern="/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/" name="host"/>
  
  IP ADDRESS :
  <input name="ip" type="text"  placeholder="IP Address" pattern="/^(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$/"/>

  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```